# Makefile.def vs Makefile.am

Tags: c, makefile, binutils

I am working on linux binutils-2.29.
In the parent directory there is not `Makefile.am`, but in all the sub directories there is `Makefile.am`.

In the parent directory these are the Makefiles present:

```
Makefile  Makefile.def  Makefile.in  Makefile.tpl
```

In side `Makefile.tpl` there is a comment which says `Makefile` is generated from `Makefile.tpl` by `autogen Makefile.def`

but inside subdirectories there is not `Makefile.def`, when I run `autoreconf && automake` it generates `Makefile` from `Makefile.am`

What exactly is the difference between `Makefile.def` and `Makefile.am`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What exactly is the difference between Makefile.def and Makefile.am?

Let's look at GCC, large project which is using `binutils` as well. Quoting [Regenerating GCC Configuration](http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Regenerating_GCC_Configuration):

> The Makefile.in file is sometimes big, and can be generated by automake from a Makefile.am file. Some Makefile.in files (used to generate Makefile in the build tree) are generated by autogen from Makefile.tpl and Makefile.def files. Autogen is a (GUILE scriptable) tool designed to simplify the creation and maintenance of programs that contain large amounts of repetitious text.

So the difference is really about how and where you want to store parts of the input files that `autogen` will work on. In case of GCC, it `Makefile.tpl` stores a **template** (for generating the output Makefile, whereas`Makefile.def` stores **definitions**, which will be used by autogen.

For example, inside `Makefile.tpl` you will find this template for filling `HOST_LIB_PATH` variable (note it uses `host_modules` variable):

```
# This is the list of directories that may be needed in RPATH_ENVVAR
# so that programs built for the host machine work.
HOST_LIB_PATH = [+ FOR host_modules +][+
  IF lib_path +]$(HOST_LIB_PATH_[+module+])[+ ENDIF lib_path +][+
  ENDFOR host_modules +]
```

And inside `Makefile.def` there is a definition for `host_modules`:

```
host_modules= { module= bfd; bootstrap=true; };
host_modules= { module= opcodes; bootstrap=true; };
// ...
```